# Install Tomcat6 as a service windows vista

Tags: windows, tomcat, service, uac

I currently am installing Tomcat6 as a windows service that will be controlled by a user account that cannot login, nor is the account a member of any groups.  The issue I am seeing is that the service will be installed, but the service stops after 20-30 seconds saying that it didn't have any work to do.  UAC is disabled at installation time, and the installation is done by a user in the administrators group.  How can I resolve this issue to ensure Tomcat properly starts up?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the steps available in the documentation for installing Tomcat 6 as a Windows service?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

> The safest way to manually install the
>   service is to use the provided
>   service.bat script. Administrator
>   privileges are required to run this
>   script.
>
> NOTE: On Windows Vista or any other
>   operating system with User Account
>   Control (UAC) you must either disable
>   UAC or right-click on cmd.exe and
>   select "Run as administrator" in order
>   to run this script. If UAC is enabled
>   being logged on with an Administrator
>   account is not sufficient.

The page provides some sample command lines to install Tomcat as a service (although the formatting does not work well when I copy and paste it into this answer).